In free-threaded Python without the GIL or other locks, can mutating an integer field on an object break the interpreter?
As of CPython 3.13, the Global Interpreter Lock can now be disabled.
When running without the GIL, I'm curious about what operations are safe, where "safe" means "does not crash or corrupt the interpreter".
Specifically, consider this example code that creates a simple class and increments/decrements an int counter on that class in parallel:
import threading
import time

class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.counter += 1
            self.counter -= 1


instance = MyObject()

for _ in range(10):
    threading.Thread(target=instance.run).start()

while True:
    print(instance.counter)
    time.sleep(1)

If run in Python (with or without the GIL), I understand that this code, which does not use any explicit locking, is racy, in that print(instance.counter) can observe non-zero values, and values can diverge over time. I am OK with that.
I am curious, however, whether free-threaded Python 3.13+ makes this code safe. Specifically:

Can attempts to access instance.counter or self.counter ever segfault, crash, or corrupt interpreter state?
Can attempts to increment or decrement instance.counter ever segfault, crash, or corrupt interpreter state?
Can retrieving and printing/copying/storing instance.counter ever retrieve an  unrepresentable or non-integer value?

I understand that the answers to this question may be implementation-specific and potentially subject to change.
I am specifically, narrowly interested in mutating numeric fields on pure-Python objects that I fully control. I understand that the presence of other code in intermediate layers of containers or accessor logic may invalidate any safety guarantees that are provided in this specific case.
What I've Tried
Running the above code displays expected race conditions in GIL-enabled and GIL-disabled interpreters I have built locally, but does not crash or emit non-integer values. That said, maybe I haven't run it for long enough or on a system that triggers specific race conditions internal to the interpreter.
Reading through the GIL removal PEP and supporting documentation for C extension developers does not indicate any provided behavior invariants regarding thread-safety where pure-Python code is concerned.
I know that interpreter-internal locks have been added (which slow down single-threaded processing) in GIL-less interpreters to prevent some instances of state corruption; I'm curious as to whether such a lock is in play in this specific instance, and if so what invariants it provides re: crash safety and observation of invalid intermediate states.
I know that explicit locking is necessary for multithreaded correctness in the presence of mutable data. However, I'm not interested in correctness, but rather safety as defined above.
Why I'm Asking

Curiosity.
Concern about safety of pre-existing code I maintain.
Interest in using this pattern to implement deliberately inaccurate mutable numbers for fuzz testing and approximation.


PEP 703, which you cited in your question, explicitly says, "This PEP proposes adding a build configuration (--disable-gil) to CPython to let it run Python code without the global interpreter lock and with the necessary changes needed to make the interpreter thread-safe." That doesn't say whether the Python version with which you are experimenting implements the option correctly, but they are supposed to implement it in a thread-safe way.

P.S., You said, "maybe I haven't run [my experiment] for long enough or on a system that triggers specific race conditions..." That's the thing, innit? If you probe for a race condition, and you get a positive result, then that proves that there's a race condition. But if you get a negative result, that proves absolutely nothing. Maybe you did it on the wrong day, on the wrong hardware, with the wrong other things running in the background, on the wrong version and update number of the OS or of the Python interpreter or on some wrong combination of any of the above. Maybe it was just luck.

still waiting for Python Concurrency in Action book. (i am sure a few people will understand this joke)

according to the linked PEP, no, reference counting is implemented in a safe way, so you cannot crash due to reference counting errors, as for Can retrieving and printing/copying/storing instance.counter ever retrieve an unrepresentable or non-integer value? that's not how race conditions work ... you can get either 0 or 1, crashes could happen in things like list if it wasn't modified to contain internal locks because it can do something like "freeing a buffer while another thread is writing to it", and without locks you get what's called "reordering", which is a beast in itself

I'm familiar with atomics and memory ordering models. However, I'm not sure how semantically atomic (not atomic-as-in-stdatomic.h) the act of retrieving, updating, and storing an integer object field is in free-threaded Python. Many interpreters implement, for example, object field updates in a thread-unsafe way internally.
Per Solomon Slow, it sounds like this is safe in terms of crashes and corruptions, but as potentially-racy in terms of data correctness as it ever was.
